# `false` unknown or invalid utility

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css, breakpoints

I'm trying to use tailwind breakpoint with twrnc (taiilwind-react-native-classnames) in my expo react native project. However, it gives me the error

> `false` unknown or invalid utility.

- I'm not using tailwindCSS, only twrnc.
- I don't have a tailwind.config.js file

```
<>
      ..........
      <View style={tw`h-1/2`}>
        {/* sm:h-1/3 *does not work* */}
        <Map />
      </View>

      <View style={tw`h-1/2`}>
        {/* sm:h-2/3 *does not work* */}
     ...........
    </>
```